# converting mysql sql to sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a MySQL SQL that works fine with Jaspersoft report:

```
SELECT pr.id AS project_id,
   pr.project_name as project_name,
   pr.export_event_id,
   au.full_name,
   ee.timestamp 
FROM (
    SELECT project.id, project.project_name, MAX(project.export_event_id) AS max_export_event_id FROM project INNER JOIN export_event iee ON project.export_event_id = iee.id
    where IIF ($P{exportEventDate} IS NULL, TRUE, CONVERT(DATE, iee.timestamp) <= $P{exportEventDate})
      GROUP BY project_name
   ) AS in_PR INNER JOIN project AS pr ON pr.project_name = in_PR.project_name AND pr.export_event_id = in_PR.max_export_event_id
   INNER JOIN project_owner_base pob ON pob.id = pr.project_owner_id
   INNER JOIN export_event AS ee ON pr.export_event_id = ee.id
   INNER JOIN auth_user au ON pob.auth_user_id = au.id
   WHERE IIF ($P{projectOwner} IS NULL, TRUE, au.id = $P{projectOwner})
```

I am trying to convert it to SQL Server but can't figure out the equivalent.

Think of the $P{...} as '?' in dynamic SQL
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just a simple OR statement.

```
Where @ProjectOwner IS NULL
OR au.id = @ProjectOwner
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is pretty close.  I would remove the `IIF()` entirely -- in either database.  The result is something like this:

```
SELECT pr.id AS project_id,
       pr.project_name as project_name,
       pr.export_event_id,
       au.full_name,
       ee.timestamp 
FROM (SELECT p.project_name, MAX(p.export_event_id) AS max_export_event_id
      FROM project p INNER JOIN
           export_event iee
           ON p.export_event_id = iee.id
      WHERE ? IS NULL OR CONVERT(DATE, iee.timestamp) <= ?
      GROUP BY p.project_name
     ) in_PR INNER JOIN
     project pr
     ON pr.project_name = in_PR.project_name AND
        pr.export_event_id = in_PR.max_export_event_id INNER JOIN
     project_owner_base pob
     ON pob.id = pr.project_owner_id INNER JOIN
     export_event ee
     ON pr.export_event_id = ee.id INNER JOIN
     auth_user au
     ON pob.auth_user_id = au.id
WHERE ? IS NULL OR au.id = ?;
```

I replaced the variables with `?` (as suggested by your question).  The above should work in either database.

Note that this also fixes the aggregation in the subquery to remove `p.id` which seems unnecessary (and should cause an error in SQL Server).